# Console doesn't log XMLHttpRequest response text when list item is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, json, xmlhttprequest, addeventlistener

I'm very new to programing in general so some of you might find this problem easily fixed, but I've tried a bunch of stuff and looked around the internet for answers but found nothing. I'm trying to load data on the fly to my site which is for a school project. To do so, I get the data from a xmlhttprequest, and my plan is to replace the current text on the page with the one I got from the request. The xmlhttprequest is run when a list-item is clicked. The project is in a very early stage.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hyr Stuga!</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body style="background-image:url(background.jpg)">
    <!-- Menu that will remain static -->
    <ul id="navbar">
        <li id="0"><a href="">Hem</a></li>
        <li id="1"><a href="">Område</a></li>
        <li id="2"><a href="">Bilder</a></li>
        <li id="3"><a href="">Kontakt</a></li>
        <li id="4" style="color:white" class="active"><a href="">Recensioner</a></li>
    </ul>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <!-- Text to be shown on startpage of page -->
    <h1>Välkommen!</h1>
    <p>Klicka på någon av menyerna för att får veta mer!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the js connected to the html file:

```
//List that contains all the items in my Navigation bar
var navBarItems = [];
for(var i=0; i < 5; i++){
    navBarItems.push(i);
}
for(var i=0; i<navBarItems.length;i++){
    navBarItems[i] = document.getElementById(i);
}


//When you click a navigation bar item, in this case the "hem" item, the console should log some JSON
navBarItems[0].addEventListener("click", function(){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/finblomma/Rudqvist/master/data.json");
    request.onload = function(){
        var recievedData = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        console.log(recievedData[0])
    };
    request.send();
});

navBarItems[1].addEventListener("click", function(){
    //...
})

//...
```

My problem is that the console doesn't log anything. I've tried sending the request with the "onload" attribute in html, and that seems to work fine. But I want it to load when I click a list item. Anyone here who knows what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that when the link is clicked, the page is reloading before the script can do it's job. What you need to do is the prevent the link from doing it's default behaviour. This can be achieved with the Javascript function `event.preventDefault();`. This function takes an event and prevents it's default behaviour from occurring. Here is some reading material to explain the function further: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp

So what you need to do, is store the `addEventListener` functions event in a variable, which in this case I have used `e`. Then inside your event listener you can just do `e.preventDefault();`

```
navBarItems[0].addEventListener("click", function(e){
    // Here is the peventDefault function. The e variable in the function above holds the event.
    e.preventDefault();
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/finblomma/Rudqvist/master/data.json");
    request.onload = function(){
        var recievedData = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        console.log(recievedData[0])
    };
    request.send();
});

navBarItems[1].addEventListener("click", function(){
})
```